# Send email with powershell in windows server 2019

Tags: powershell, email, outlook, office-automation, windows-server-2019

I use a script to send mail from powershell, through outlook:

```
Try{
$ol = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application
$mail = $ol.CreateItem(0)
$mail.To = ""
$mail.Subject = "Test from PS"
$mail.Display( $true )
$ol.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ol) | Out-Null
}
Catch{ write-host [ERROR] $Error }
```

It works correctly in windows 10, but in server 2019 the sent message remains in the outbox, and it is only sent if I enter outlook expressly.

Is there something missing from the script to force outlook to immediately send the generated message?

I have tested it with outlook 2019 and 2021
In outlook options, programmatic access is 'never warn me about suspicious activity'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code creates a new mail item in Outlook and then display it to a user by calling the `Display` method:

```
$mail.Display( $true )
```

Which I suppose doesn't make any sense on the server side.

If you need to send the mail item you need to call the `Send` method instead of `Display` one. So, the code may look like that:

```
Try{
$ol = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application
$olNamespace = $ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$mail = $ol.CreateItem(0)
$mail.To = ""
$mail.Subject = "Test from PS"
$mail.Send()
$olNamespace.SendAndReceive(false);
$ol.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ol) | Out-Null
}
Catch{ write-host [ERROR] $Error }
```

Also you may try using the [NameSpace.SendAndReceive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.sendandreceive) method which initiates immediate delivery of all undelivered messages submitted in the current session, and immediate receipt of mail for all accounts in the current profile. `SendAndReceive` provides the programmatic equivalent to the `Send/Receive All` command that is available when you click `Tools` and then `Send/Receive`.

If you don't need to synchronize all objects, you can use the [SyncObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.syncobjects) collection object to select specific objects. For more information, see [NameSpace.SyncObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.syncobjects). It makes sense to wait until the sync process is finished and only then close Outlook by calling the `Quit` method. The [SyncObject.SyncEnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.syncobject.syncend) event is fired immediately after Microsoft Outlook finishes synchronizing a user's folders using the specified `Send/Receive` group.

Also be aware, Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) article.

As a possible workaround you may consider using the Graph API or EWS, see [Send email messages by using EWS in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-send-email-messages-by-using-ews-in-exchange?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for more information.

Comment: I agree with your considerations about the server, and the indicated problem is due to a temporary and very specific issue. It is an access via rdp for a certain user, who must send some messages, once they have been edited. That's why I can't use .Send, but .Display, and present the outlook form to it. For the rest, your suggestion to use .SendAndReceive solves my problem, with a little tweak because after the .Display the outlook object is invalidated.